# Embedding youtube video with only play,pause and refresh buttons

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I want to embed youtube video in my website. My requirement is that the player should have only three options: play, pause and refresh. I want to disable the progressbar slider so that viewer can not move forward or backward.

I used the parameter "controls=0", but it removes the progressbar completely. I just want to disable the dragging functionality.

Anybody knows how to do this?

Comment: what if the user wants to mute the video?

Comment: no restriction on that..

Answer (score 0):

setting `autohide=2` should do it.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#autohide